# Oracle: clob column inconsistent with itself in UNION statement ORA-00932

Tags: oracle

I'm getting an ORA-00932 doing the UNION of 2 tables in Oracle. I don't have much experience with this database.

I reduced the problem till the union of the CLOB column with itself, but still get the error. Here is the command:

```
SELECT nm_wkt FROM UR_C99.CD_VET
UNION
SELECT nm_wkt FROM UR_C99.CD_VET
```

And I get the error (in Portuguese):

```
SQL Error [932] [42000]: ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava - obteve CLOB
```

The column definition is just `nm_wkt CLOB NOT NULL`.

I wasn't expecting to get the error at this point. It's just a simple union statement. I'll need to redo a lot of work if I can't make this union.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Must use UNION ALL so the clob columns won't be compared:

```
SELECT nm_wkt FROM UR_C39.CD_VET_GEOBNDES
UNION all
SELECT nm_wkt FROM UR_C39.CD_VET_GEOBNDES
```